# How to convert a species by species interaction matrix into a dataframe?

Tags: r, networking, interaction, bipartite

I have a species by species interaction network, with predator identity in the first row and prey identity in the first column. The matrix is filles with 0 or 1 representing the presence or absence of an interaction. I would like to convert this matrix into a dataframe with two columns, the first column containing the identity of the predator and the second the identity of the prey. Thus each row would be defined by a different predator-prey combinaison, representing a unique interaction.
Here is how it should look like:

```
int.matrix <- matrix(c(1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0),nrow=4,ncol=4)
rownames(int.matrix)<-c("prey1","prey2","prey3","prey4")
colnames(int.matrix)<-c("pred1","pred2","pred3","pred4")
int.matrix

        pred1 pred2 pred3 pred4
prey1     1     0     1     0
prey2     1     1     0     1
prey3     0     0     0     0
prey4     1     0     1     0

L1 <- c("pred1","pred1","pred1","pred2","pred3","pred3","pred4")
L2 <- c("prey1","prey2","prey4","prey2","prey1","prey4","prey2")
data.frame(cbind(L1,L2))

     L1    L2
1 pred1 prey1
2 pred1 prey2
3 pred1 prey4
4 pred2 prey2
5 pred3 prey1
6 pred3 prey4
7 pred4 prey2
```

Thank you very much

Valerie

Answer (score 0):

You could use `as.table` and `data.frame`, like this:

```
> x <- data.frame(as.table(int.matrix))
> x[x$Freq == 1, 1:2]
    Var1  Var2
1  prey1 pred1
2  prey2 pred1
4  prey4 pred1
6  prey2 pred2
9  prey1 pred3
12 prey4 pred3
14 prey2 pred4
```

---

When you use `data.frame` on a `table`, you get a "long" `data.frame`. Since this `data.frame` would also include "0" values, you select just the rows where the `Freq` column is equal to 1.

Answer (score 0):

You may also try:

```
indx <- !!int.matrix
data.frame(Var1=rownames(indx)[row(indx)][indx], Var2=colnames(indx)[col(indx)][indx])
#   Var1  Var2
#1 prey1 pred1
#2 prey2 pred1
#3 prey4 pred1
#4 prey2 pred2
#5 prey1 pred3
#6 prey4 pred3
#7 prey2 pred4
```

Or

```
indx <- (1:4)*int.matrix 
data.frame(Var1=row.names(int.matrix)[indx], Var2=colnames(int.matrix)[indx])
```

Or

```
library(reshape2)
res <- melt(!!int.matrix)
res[res$value,-3]
```